# Configuring PHP 5.3.5 In Apache

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, php, configuration

I just reformatted my computer, installed PHP 5.3.5 & Apache the problem was that when installing I didn't get an option to integrate with Apache.

[image]

My PHP dir looks like

[image]

Missing the php5apache22.dll (hope i spelled it right) how can I fix this and integrate with apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [these instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php) step by step.

--EDIT--

Reading the [manual install page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php) you find the [right version](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.3.5-Win32-VC6-x86.zip) to download, in which there is the dll you need.

Comment: I am missing the `php5apache2_2.dll` when I try reinstalling PHP 5.3.5 again, its still not there. Is there something wrong with my install? When I install PHP 5.3.3, I dont get this problem

Comment: I add details to my answer.

Comment: The only diff was I used the VC9 msi version, shouldn't that (VC9) be better? **UPDATE**: Oh VC9 is not for Apache? icic

Comment: I just tried installing VC6 msi version, its still missing the option to integrate with Apache? must I really install manually? I used the non-thread-safe version is it right?

Comment: nvm I solved the problem using VC6 Thread Safe PHP. Just curious then, whats VC6 Non-Thread Safe for?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see Apache into the de radio bottons options, you need to install the Thread Safe One!

Check it out:
http://www.websiteadministrator.com.au/articles/install_guides/installing_php535_pg4.html